# Object evaluate is always null in Android Studio debug

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

I have found a weird behavior while debugging in Android Studio. I am using a real device (not an emulator). I have the following code:

```
 val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_navhost_fragment)
            if (currentFragment is BottomNavFragment) {
            ...
```

In debug I see the following:
[image]

As you may see, currentFragment is not null. However, if I try to evaluate only the expression
supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_navhost_fragment), the result is null.

[image]

How is it possible? I know it's probably a very silly question but I don't understand why evaluate expression gives a different result compare to runtime code, maybe it's because of fragment id? Is there a way to evaluate such expressions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a kotlin bug, R values are resolved incorrectly.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-18232

Workaround I have found is to copy the correct R.id.* int value (eg printing a log or directly from R file) and replace the R.id.* with the copied int.